# How to check expired seesion data in codeigniter for redirect

Tags: session, codeigniter-3, session-cookies

I have two user types "Customer" & "Vendor" and I am setting them in session during login process but a little confused on how to achieve a functionality like if the user_type is vendor then when the session timeout automatically so when I click on reload it should be supposed to redirect on the vendor side login.

If user type was customer then after session timeout, if somebody reloads the page it loads the customer side login.

Answer (score 0):

> Check session user data then load the page

```
<?php
  if($this->session->userdata('user_type') == 'vendor'){
    $this->load->view('vendor_screen'); }
  else{
    $this->load->view('customer_screen');    
  } 
?>
```

Comment: session is expired, so how does it possible? btw it is saying undefined index user_type

Comment: `if(!empty($this->session->userdata('user_type'))`

Comment: change the if condition as above it will not show you the error

Comment: and what happened if it empty? still showing the same error

Comment: Show the customer screen when it is empty